# symfony installer failure with locale

Tags: php, symfony

i ve been trying to create a project using symfony installer following this article: [Installing and Configuring Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html)

However i ve run into some problems i dont understand. The terminal output after giving the command:

```
symfony new beta
```

is:

```
Downloading Symfony...

4.92 MB/4.92 MB ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓  100%

Preparing project...

PHP Warning:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/src/Symfony/Installer/NewCommand.php on line 270
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/symfony:0
PHP   2. require() /usr/local/bin/symfony:10
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/symfony:35
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
PHP   7. Symfony\Installer\NewCommand->execute() phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:252
PHP   8. Symfony\Installer\NewCommand->dumpReadmeFile() phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/src/Symfony/Installer/NewCommand.php:61
PHP   9. date() phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/src/Symfony/Installer/NewCommand.php:270



[Symfony\Component\Intl\Exception\MethodArgumentValueNotImplementedException]                                                                                                   
The Symfony\Component\Intl\Collator\Collator::__construct() method's argument $locale value 'fr_FR' behavior is not implemented. Only the locale "en" is supported.  Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities.                                                                 

new directory [version]
```

I don't remember ever installing french on my machine, and although i like the sound of the language i can't speak it. In my phpinfo() i can find nothing about locale and have no idea how to go on from this point, either in changing the locale on my machine, or by changing the locale in the symfony settings, perhaps?

php: 5.5.24
os: fedora 20

Comment: I don't know Fedora too well but this is all a php.ini issue.  You can run `php -i | grep ini` from the command line to see where your php.ini files may be stored.  You'll need to make sure it has `date.timezone = America/Detroit` or whatever timezone you'd like and `intl.default_locale = en`.  Restart apache or whatever server you're running and try again.  Sometimes there's more than one php.ini, one for apache and one for the cmd line tool.  So make sure you check all of them.

Comment: half way there. i updated the date.timezone entry first, and the message about date was suppressed. so i guess i alter the correct php.ini. but after changing the `intl.default_locale = en` the same error about locale was produced

Comment: Well that sucks.  The only easier way would be to make sure php_intl is installed.  It usually is with any basic php5 install but sometimes not.  so maybe try `yum install php-intl` or `yum search php-intl` or `yum search php` to find the correct package name for your repo.  Then restart and try again.

Comment: yeap. installing the php-intl solved the problem. although it's really dissapointing having to install a php module for a framework... thank you mate.

Comment: All part and parcel to having things run smoothly.  I'll post an answer for you to accept if you would so kindly. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comments for more detail, in short.

Make sure `date.timezone = America/Detroit` is set in your php.ini.  You can find where your config is by running `php -i | grep ini` from the command line.

Also make sure php-intl is installed.  It usually is with most php5 installs but if not try running `yum install php-intl` or use `yum search php` to find the correct package name.

Restart your server and try the install again.